# Website won't load on IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-9

Afternoon, i've been struggling with this.

this url simply wont load on IE9.

I opened the developer tools and i get "Text - Empty Text Node" below every single element. It works on all other IE versions and all the browsers. It's only on IE9 that wont load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It *might* work more reliably if the [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftubolsillo.do&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) are fixed.

Comment: Try placing your JS codes at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It seems like you're using some HTML5 tags... You'll either want to get rid of those or change the doctype to `!DOCTYPE html`.

Comment: Those validation errors are mostly g+ and facebook buttons properties. The ones that I could fix are fixed

Comment: It loads fine in IE9 for me, so I don't see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "compatibly view" in IE9? When you are at the bad page, click the "broken page" icon in the address bar (between search and refresh). It doesn't work for every site, but it might just be the trick to fix yours!

[image: screenshot]